# SSIS solution - Developed with 32-bit ODBC driver. Need to make some tweaks to the solution to run with 64-bit ODBC driver

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, ssis, odbc

At the moment we have a solution running fine under the 32 bit ODBC driver in DEV environment and this 32 bit ODBC driver doesn't exists in PROD.  There is a 64 bit ODBC driver in PROD though. I did an initial attempt to make it run under the 64-bit version of the driver, but it was giving me errors.

How do I get the 64-bit ODBC connection working for our packages in PROD. What changes I will have to make to my existing solution?

Comment: An idea what errors you got would help a lot here. SQL Server and ODBC have such a selection of options, I hardly know where to begin. /s

Comment: We need a lot more information, even if you just copy/paste the errors you are getting. I have done the same thing and had not errors many times, but sometimes thing comes up, such as a deprecated function that is being used.

Comment: Create a SQL Server Agent Job to run the package. In the properties of the job step, you can specify that the 64-bit-runtime has to  be used.

Comment: The error I am getting - "ODBC Source" failed validation and returned validation status "VS_NEEDSNEWMETADATA" @LaughingVergil

Comment: A VS_NEEDSNEWMETADATA error means that the metadata stored in the package is out of sync with the actual data source. Usually, the fix is to right-click on the data source returning the error and select Edit. SSIS should prompt you with a question asking if it should fix the meta data. Choosing "yes" usually fixes the issue. You may wish to do this on all of the data sources in the package, just for safety sake. If you aren't asked about fixing the metadata, don't bother re-saving that data source.

Comment: @LaughingVergil : But the package is running absolutely fine from Visual Studio which uses 32 Bit ODBC connector. When I run from the SQL Server Agent (using 64 bit ODBC connector), I am getting this error. Does your solution work in this scenario?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay. I got it to work.

I was using **32 bit ODBC **Unicode** driver in Visual Studio and **64 bit ODBC **ANSI** Driver in SQL Server Agent. **It is because of the differences in Unicode and ANSI drivers the Metadata went out of sync.**

**Solution:** Set **validateExternalMetadata property to ‘false’** on all the source or destination components in the package.

Answer (score 0):

It should. I would not be at all surprised if the 64 bit ODBC driver used different metadata around the size of an int

Comment: I got it to work. Please see my below comment for the solution. Thanks a lot for your suggestions @Laughing Vergil :)